# Plotting points from only certain rows in a matrix in R

Tags: r

I am new to R so it's probably very basic, but I am trying to add colored points for certain values to a plot of a matrix "m". I need to add points from the same matrix, but *only* for the rows containing values within the range 169 to 179. What code can I use for this? I tried:

```
p <- which(m[,2]==169:179
## and
points (p, col="blue")
```

and it doesn't work. How can I write these codes properly to put these coordinates in blue on the graph? 
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would be good if you could share an example of your data. In general it makes more sense to plot data from a data frame, opposed to a matrix. We can use the pre-installed `mtcars` dataset to demonstrate your solution.

Let's first have a look at the data available in the dataset:

```
summary(mtcars)
```

Next, we can filter the data that we want to display. In this case we are filtering `mtcars$mpg` (the column with the name `mpg`) for values between 15 and 20. To make it easier, we assign this filtered data frame as a new data frame.

```
mtcars_filtered <- mtcars[mtcars$mpg >= 15 & mtcars$mpg <= 20 , ]
```

Lastly, we can plot the data. In this case, we want the `mpg` column to be the x values and `hp` to be the y values. `type` is used to specify how we want to display it (`"p"` for points), and `col` is used to specify the color (`"blue"` for blue).

```
plot(mtcars_filtered$mpg, mtcars_filtered$hp, type = 'p', col = 'blue')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define a function that test if a number is in between your two values:

```
inbetween = function(x)
{
     return ( x >= 169 & x <= 179 )
}
```

And then call it on each value of m[,2] with the function sapply:
`ind = sapply( m[,2], inbetween )`
Which gives you a vector of True or False according if the given value if in the range or not.
Then taking `p = m[ind,]` will give you the rows of m at those selected indices.

Comment: Why not just `m[,2] <= 179 & m[,2] >= 169`. R isn't great at function calls

Comment: oh yes, much simpler indeed !